# Adjust footer in MS Word to compensate for portrait/landscape orientation with the table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, headers, footers, table-styles

In my footer I have a table which I would like to adjust to fit the entire width of the page.

I have used Alignment tab to set it up:
[image: Portrait]

But when the orientation of the page changes, the table is not lengthened accordingly:
[image: Landscape].

Is there a way to set up the table in the header to also adjust it's size depending on the orientation of the page?

Expected header for landscape:
[image: Expected header for landscape]?

Comment: Have you tried [autofit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/resize-a-table-column-or-row-9340d478-21be-4392-81cf-488f7bbd6715)? How exactly you've "used alignment tab"?

Comment: Yes, I have tried Autofit but it would adjust the table only to fit the portrait page. Problem remains for Landcape.

Inserted the table first, then "Autofit to window", followed by "Insert Alignment tab -> Left" and so on.

Comment: Do you have "Link to Previous" selected for the header? If yes, try disabling it and making a separate header for landscape paper

Comment: Disabled "Link to previous" and it worked.